# Prop Shortcut in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been using the shortcut for creating properties for a few weeks now (Prop + tab + tab). Recently intellisense has changed it so when I type in Prop it auto corrects to "Protected" key word. If I type Prop, then backspace out of Protected, then Prop + Tab + Tab works again. How do I tell intellisense not to use "Protected" any more by default?

Comment: Tools -> Code Snippet Manager, change language to CSharp and Search for "prop". These are the "Shortcuts" do you mean.

Comment: Toos >> Export Import settings >> Reset all settings. Sometimes the ide behaviour gets alteres dut to installation of some extension or some other way. Resetting should solve the issue

Comment: 2nd one worked. Yogi if you would like to add the 2nd response as an answer i can mark it for you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Toos >> Export Import settings >> Reset all settings.

Sometimes the IDE behavior gets altered due to installation of some extension or some other way. Resetting should solve the issue.